# Firebase Error on Production Server, Dev is ok. Using Angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

http://plnkr.co/edit/G43dqi8H4dn6d8oXdvyy

I think the following problem is due to the way I'm loading firebase data because putting data calls inside setTimeouts has an effect on dev server but the same doesn't help with production server, even if the timeouts are cranked way high.

Perfectly working development version breaks on gh-pages. I've tested the production version using http-server and works. However once gh-pages get's it, it gives the following error thrown on `var indexRef = new Firebase(refString);`:

> Error: new Firebase failed: First argument must be a valid firebase
>   URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".

here's the  [gh-pages link](http://irthos.github.io/metal01/#/) and here's [the repo, it's small just one partial-view/route/controller](https://github.com/irthos/metal01)

Able to reproduce error seen on gh-pages with Firebase's own hosting, as well.

```
angular.module('metal01').controller('LandingCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', 'Firebase', '$window', '$location' , function($scope, $firebase, Firebase, $window, $location){

 // get host url and format to match db index key
    var location = $location.host();
    location.toLowerCase().replace(/'+/g, '').replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, "-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');

 // getting firebase reference for host url index
    var refString = "https://tezt.firebaseio.com/metal/index/domains/"+ location;



// This is throwing error!
    var indexRef = new Firebase(refString);



    var indexSync = $firebase(indexRef);
    var indexArray = indexSync.$asArray();
    var indexObject = indexSync.$asObject();

    setTimeout(function(){

     // create firebase objects in timeout to avoid undefined while loading.

        var domainRef = 'https://tezt.firebaseio.com/metal/domains/'+indexObject.$value;
        var ref = new Firebase(domainRef);
        var sync = $firebase(ref);
        var mediaSync = $firebase(mediaRef);
        $scope.data = sync.$asObject();
        $scope.list = sync.$asArray();
        $scope.media = mediaSync.$asArray();
        $scope.height = $window.innerHeight;
        $scope.location = $location.host();
    },2000);
    var mediaRef = new Firebase("https://tezt.firebaseio.com/metal/media/");
}]);
```

Comment: Can you give me plunker/jsfiddle/codepen where i can look into this ?

Comment: @CrazyGeek sure thing.. http://plnkr.co/edit/G43dqi8H4dn6d8oXdvyy
the idea is that this app takes the current domain name, checks it against a list of indexed domain names that reference data for specific domains. If it's a match (after formatting), the site data is returned.

Comment: Thanks, I got your idea and will try to resolve in very optimized way that will help you. :)

Comment: thanks bud! I tried to put the firebase calls in a service and inject into state controller via a resolve property but was running into the same errors still. i probz wasn't using $q right tho..